# sum input field with store number in character

Tags: javascript

I need to sum input field, the difficult thing is I need to store `a=1 b=2 c=3` to `z` so every character will have number.  The input field is character like `a` and sum the number of `a` with `5` and display the new character.

I tried with this code but I can't store number in character:

```
<input type="text" id="my_input1" />
<input type="text" id="my_input2" />
<input type="button" value="Add Them Together" onclick="doMath();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doMath()
    {
        var my_input1 = document.getElementById('my_input1').value;
        var my_input2 = document.getElementById('my_input2').value;
        var sum = parseInt(my_input1) + parseInt(my_input2);
        document.write(sum);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/8kd1w8xb/

Comment: When using `parseInt`, don't forget to precise the `base` parameter ! It's important, you could have some unexpected results. See this : https://davidwalsh.name/parseint-radix

Comment: @ Bhojendra Nepal yes this code worked but i need something different

Comment: Don't do `document.write(sum);`  "document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open, which will clear the document." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function doMath() {
  var charMap = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4
  }; //add more as needed
  // note I make NO attempt to ensure the entered value exists here.
  var my_input1 = document.getElementById('my_input1').value;
  var my_input2 = document.getElementById('my_input2').value;
  console.log(charMap[my_input1], charMap[my_input2]);
  var sum = charMap[my_input1] + charMap[my_input2];
  document.getElementById('showresult').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="my_input1" />
<input type="text" id="my_input2" />
<input type="button" value="Add Them Together" onclick="doMath();" />
<div id="showresult"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `charCodeAt` to get the character code of a letter:

```
'a'.charCodeAt(0)  // 97
```

If you want to define a custom number for each character than you will have to declare an object like:

```
let values = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
values.a // 1
```

Comment: thank you for reply and yes i need to define a custom number for each character so can you give me the complete code? cause i don't know how to make it